# WSO IS 5.3.0: user dashboard not working out of the box

Tags: wso2, dashboard, jaggery-js, wso2-identity-server

I'm evaluating WSO2 identity server for a customer of mine and currently we ponder whether to write our own user dashboard or use WSO2's version of it.

According to WSO 5.3.0 it's as easy as opening /dashboard. I don't find anything about how to install or enable the user dashboard and I didn't find a module I could install. Therefore I think that this should work out of the box. Yet, when I open the URL I get an error:

> HTTP Status 500 - org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError:
>   "readFile" is not defined. (/dashboard//login.jag#47)
>
> type Status report
>
> message org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "readFile"
>   is not defined. (/dashboard//login.jag#47)
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request. Apache Tomcat/7.0.73

I tried to find the cause of this issue but the log files are in no way more verbose and after looking at the includes of login.ja redFile seems to be defined.

Can anybody please point me towards something that helps me solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The dashboard is working out of the box and no installation is required. Make sure you are running on JDK 7 or 8.

Comment: Yes, I'm using JDK 8. As for the dashboard, maybe it should work out of the box, but clearly it isn't as I'm getting this error. The question remains: How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason (that are still to explore) three modules that were in the installation archive were missing from the actual installation. The modules were: caramel, handlebar and markdown. After installing them from the archive the dashboard started working.

Installing caramel only didn't work and my guess is that markdown is not necessary to run the dashboard but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found that is does not work with Safari.  Identity Manager does.
I originally tried it on MacBook pro.
When I tried it with Chrome all is well.